# How can I create a Postgres user and database whenever I create a new rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rails-postgresql

I have followed this really helpful tutorial:

http://blog.willj.net/2011/05/31/setting-up-postgresql-for-ruby-on-rails-development-on-os-x/

I would really like to run `rails new myapp` and have the postgres db set up automatically. Is there any way I can do that using a [Rails application template](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html) or something similar?

Comment: I suppose I could create a user and database that I use for all my little test applications. However for larger stuff I obviously want separate databases.

Answer (score 15):

On a unix based system:

```
sudo -u postgres createuser -d -R -P APPNAME
sudo -u postgres createdb -O APPNAME APPNAME
```

You can create a script and put it somewhere in your $PATH if you can't remember.

Comment: You shouldn't need sudo for those command - only a "superuser" account for the Postgres database.

Comment: Just for completion sake,  
`createuser -d -R -P will create a user that can create a db (-d), can't create role (-R), and prompt for password(-P)`  

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-createuser.html  
  
`createdb -O will create a db with the specified owner (-O)`  

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-createdb.html

Answer (score 9):

Actually you don't need to create a new user each time you create a new rails app.

All you have to do is create the new application and change the `username` in your `database.yml`

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: newapp_development
  pool: 5
  username: #your username
  password:
...
```

than just:

```
rake db:create:all
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I didn't realise that. Is there anyway I can customise that database.yml file as it's created? I know it's two seconds to change it but I just like being able to quickly try out different ideas.

Comment: You can create a database template... I haven't tried yet, but there is a [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/148-app-templates-in-rails-2-3) about it.

Comment: Really great screencast. I want to create a template.rb file with   `'config/database.yml',
%Q{stuff for database.yml here}` However I need to get the name of the app into the template.rb file. Is that possible?