# Config postgres to accept any user/password combination in development mode

Tags: postgresql, authentication, development-environment

Doing freelance, I keep on getting on new projets.

I find postgresql config highly complicated when being used in development mode only (I totally understand that production requirements are much different).

What I want to achieve is to config my postgres so that whatever username/password/port/connexion mode is used, it has all the rights on the DB (as security is no matter here). Working with Rails, all the config is in `config/database.yml` and I don't want to change anything from the file itself.

I achieved having any password_less authentication for every connexion (local and TCP), but doing this:

```
# /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             all                                     trust
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               trust
```

And:

```
# /etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf
listen_addresses = '*'
```

As from this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278379/how-to-configure-postgresql-to-accept-all-incoming-connections).

But if the user (eg. `appname_dev`) doesn't exists, I get:

```
FATAL:  role "appname_dev" does not exist
```

This [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819841/how-can-i-create-a-postgres-user-and-database-whenever-i-create-a-new-rails-app) allows me to create the user in 1 line, which is fair enough (`sudo -u postgres createuser -d -R -P appname_dev`), but I would really like this to be plug and play.

- How can I achieve that?
- Ain't there any development installation mode on postgres where by default, credentials would be much lighter configured that the current one?
- Am I missing some best practice that make this not being a problem?

I understand the port thing can be tricky, but IMHO, the rest should not!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It seems you want [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org) except it's not fully compatible with postgres at the SQL level.

Comment: SQLite does fit most of my requirements. But what I'd like is a working db out of the box, without having to edit any single config file meaning the choice of Postgres + Username + Password is already made, not by me.

Comment: You can only connect with users that do exist in the database. There is no way around that. Is there some "bootstrap" schema setup code in your dev-environment? You could include the necessary `create user` script there and as everybody can connect as the superuser, everybody can run that bootstrap code.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting solution, I shall have a look at it!

Comment: What existing role would you like it to assume instead of a non-existing one, Augustin?

Comment: I've skimmed through the source, the only way to change the behavior would be to patch `InitializeSessionUserId` and either add a new Id there if it doesn't exist, or replace the one coming in for a completely different one. This begs the question, why don't you just use an existing user to begin with?

Comment: Well, I get on projects with existing codebase. Some of them include DB connexion configuration (username and password) for local environment. And I don't really see a good reason to change their value when my local environment DB should be in *development mode*, meaning accepting any config.

Comment: Otherwise, it is the man bending to the machine's desires!

Comment: I have a similar application requirement. I wrote a script ( bash/python ) doesn't matter, that will create and set up the database, users, etc on install. That script is run as part of my 'install' step ( it's not really install, but similar .. )

Answer (score 0):

You may achieve this by using pgbouncer (connection pooler) with following settings:

```
* = host=127.0.0.1 user=postgres
auth_type = any
```

so when you connect to pgbouncer with any user and any password it will connect to postgres as postgres user which has all permissions.

You may also want to change pgbouncer port to 5432 (by default it works on 6432 port) and change postgres port to something different so your application will connect to pgbouncer without any modifications in configs.